# full text search index on main table or should I create another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an [Ads] table where there are 100s of thousands of records.

I want to implement full text search.

But I will display data on main page of my application that contains all records (of course paging is used)

I want to know can I implement full text search index on table [Ads] or should I create another table where searchable fields like description and address are present?

When I use query like

```
select * from Ads
```

if full text index is used, does it slow the fetching process?

Comment: The index is separate from data itself, so having a full text index shouldn't really affect the performance of other queries.  Having very large text fields *can* affect performance, particularly when the fields cause records to span multiple pages.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So what should I do? what are u suggesting? I was thinking creating another table with some duplicate fields but as you said it's not needed. I have description with 1000 varchar and address with 500 varchar, is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Build the full text index on the table as it is.

Comment: You don't really want to do a Select *.  While a single varchar 1000 isn't going to be horribly invasive to return in a simple UI it just might not fit properly, in which case why select it unless you have to.  you COULD use 'large value types out of row' and change it to a varchar Max, but it could also be overkill.  Anyway the Full text index is unlikely to cause performance problems in the scenario you've described selecting the full varchar 1000 field before you actually need it is more likely to hurt performance.